# Render post content in textarea wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to retrieve my post content with the formatting content in my textarea.
But my textarea display `p` & `br` tags event if I use all the php functions I know..

My variable :

```
$content = $postdata->post_content; $event_description = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

My textarea :

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="event_description" required><?php echo html_entity_decode($event_description);?></textarea>
```

Outside the textarea, the text is displaying well..

How to render correctly the content ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the answer !

I need to do that :

```
$content = $postdata->post_content; 
$event_description = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$event_description = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show textarea value as below:

```
<textarea name="text"><?php echo  html_entity_decode($text); ?></textarea>
```

It will change HTML tags to proper HTML design. Hope it helps you.